# How do you query sent items using gmail api?

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, gmail-api

When I use label:sent as a search query in the gmail UI it takes me to sent items but when I use a labelId of sent from the gmail API for messages (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) I get an error "Invalid label: sent" - just wondering how do I query for sent items from the API? Also is there a reference / examples for the type of input you can use for the "q" input parameter for the gmail API?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing a list with "?labelId=" then use "SENT" (in upper case) as per:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels
(those should probably be case insensitive but they are not.)

For the "?q=" parameter to the list methods it says on the URL you give:

> Supports the same query format as the Gmail search box. For example, "from:someuser@example.com rfc822msgid: is:unread".

For more examples, I just tried searching for "gmail search queries" and got:

> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

which gives lots of useful keywords, they should all work with the "q=" parameter (you may need to URL escape them, depending on language/client libraries).